# Why are there so many memory grants?

Tags: sql-server

My website handles a large number of concurrent requests - all requesting the same stored proc to be run.

I notice that there are a large number of memory grant requests when I run this dmv query :

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants
```

Is this because I should be allocating more memory for each query? Currently it is set to 1024 KB minimum memory per query.

Comment: Define large in this case, relative to the number of queries

Comment: Is it normal to have 20 - 40 grant requests when you run this query? Or does this indicate that there is consistently less memory?

Comment: It will be one memory grant per running query.  Unless you are experiencing a problem and memory pressure is the root cause then you should leave your settings alone, don't be one of those guys that pokes it with a stick until it works.

Comment: What is a good way to determine memory pressure? Im trying to increase the system's ability to handle a large number of concurrent requests. I am seeing some increase in execution time with high concurrency - execution time spikes up (at times) to 400ms, where as typically it takes only 58ms. I am actually trying to see if there is anything I can do to resolve this.